# Why can't a dictionary with mutable values be reversed?

Tags: python, dictionary, immutability, mutable

I am trying this simple function that switches the keys and values for a given dictionary:

```
def reverse_dict(d):
    return {y:x for x,y in d.items()}
```

Works fine if the values are immutable, however if one of the values is a list I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Why does the value have to be immutable for this function to work?
I'm interested in what happens in terms of python's memory model.